# Encryption: TCB (Tweaked CodeBook) algorithm - what is it?

Tags: encryption, ecb, block-cipher

Can someone please provide a description of TCB algorithm?

Comment: Yes. Wikipedia doesn't have any. I didn't find anything in Google also. There are a lot of references to it on the net, but I saw precise description nowhere. There is a way to find out by for example taking TrueCrypt sources, but... I am not good in C++ and that may take too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My cryptographic skills are a little bit rusty - but IMHO, Tweaked Codebook = [Tweakable Block Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Tweakable_block_ciphers).

It's basically ECB with a *Tweak*, that "patches" [ECB's biggests flaws](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap7.pdf): identical plaintext blocks result in identical ciphertext (exposing your ciphertext to malicious substitution and showing data patterns).

With a plaintext message P, cut in n-bits blocks X1, X2, X3... Xi... Xn

1. Xi (XOR) Tweak(i) -> CC
2. Encrypt_function(CC) -> Ci

Depending on your implementation, your *Tweak* is generated using a function of your choice (taking your block number as a parameter). A very simple (unsecure?) one could be:

- Tweak(i) = i

I'm not 100% OK with my answer; at least that's what I remember and that's what I get when looking at an extract of IEEE 1619-2007. I'd really like to read more on this!

Comment: I got one doc on implementation from the link you provided to WikiPedia: http://axelkenzo.ru/index.php?downloads=1619-2007-NIST-Submission.pdf
It looks like it has some clues ;)

Comment: Yep. I didn't put this link in my answer - it seems like there's a copyright issue with this document (see page 1). Keep us updated!